# Is this JavaScript two dimensional array?

Tags: javascript

```
const monsters = {
  '1': {
    name: 'godzilla',
    age: 250000000
  },
  '2': {
    Name: 'manticore',
    age: 21
  }
}
```

I learn JavaScript from Codecademy, What does this code mean?
Is this two dimensional array? If not, what is it?

Comment: It is two JS objects with properties inside a third outer JS object. If you consider objects as associative arrays or Hashes or maps, then the outer object has a key 1 and a key 2 with objects as values.

Answer (score 3):

The data structure you are showing in your code example is not an array at all, it is an object. Arrays are defined using square brackets (`[]`) and their keys (indices) are not explicitly declared but rather assigned automatically.

So if you wrote your code like this, for example, you would have an array containing objects:

```
const monsters = [
  {
    name: 'godzilla',
    age: 250000000
  },
  {
    name: 'manticore',
    age: 21
  }
]
```

…so you could access the values by their array index, like so.

```
monsters[0].name; // godzilla
monsters[1].name; // manticore
```

Comment: This is JSON object